# Let $f \colon X \rightarrow X$ continuous. Show that if $X = [0,1]$, then there exists a point $x$ such that $f(x) = x$

Tags: general-topology

Let $f \colon X \rightarrow X$ continuous. Show that if $X = [0,1]$, then there exists a point $x$ such that $f(x) = x$. The point $x$ is called the fixed point of $f$. What happens if $X$ is the space $[0,1)$ or the space $(0,1)$?

The first part is already done. But I have not been able to know what happens if $ X = [0,1) $ or $ X = (0,1) $. Could you give me any suggestion?

I have noticed that if I define $ g(x) = f (x)-x $, the intermediate value theorem might not be applicable to $g $.

When $ X = [0,1) $ I have the counterexample $ f (x) = \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2}$. But when X = (0,1) the case will be the same?

Comment: Note that $f (x) - x \geq 0$ at $x=0$, while $ f(x) - x \leq 0$ at $x=1$.

Comment: Let $g(x) = f(x)-x$ and consider $g(0) = f(0)$ and $g(1) = f(1)-1$. How does the IVT allow us to guarantee a $0$ of $g$ in $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x)=\frac{1}{2} x$ is not a counterexample for $X=[0,1)$ as $0$ is a fixed point.
It *does* work for $X=(0,1)$. Caffeinemachine has a useful idea for $X=[0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks I just realized that the counterexample is $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} x + \frac{1}{2} $ for $X = [0,1)$

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $X=[0, 1)$. Then $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y:=[0, \infty)$. So if we can find a continuous function $Y\to Y$ which does not have a fixed point, then we can find such a function for $X$ too. But coming up with such a function for $Y$ is easy. Just take $f:Y\to Y$ as $f(y) = 1+y$ and we are done.

Similarly, when $X=(0, 1)$ then $X$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: This looks like a basic calculus question - the notion of homeomorphism may not have been defined yet.  There are some easy explicit counterexamples for functions $f:[0,1) \rightarrow [0,1)$ etc., but I think I'll let the OP work them out.

Comment: @JairTaylor The tag is generel-topology.

Comment: Oh, did not notice that, fair point.